Failed to execute the build ... configured Dockerfile doesn't exist. But the file DO exists
guys,
I get
[ERROR] F8: Failed to execute the build: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Configured Dockerfile "{PROJECT_DIR}\target\docker-file\Dockerfile" (resolved to "{PROJECT_DIR}\target\docker-file\Dockerfile") doesn't exist

but I haven't configured anywhere this target/docker-file.
On the contrary - in pom.xml I have
        <profile>
            <id>...</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                        <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <build>
                                        <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                                        <contextDir>${project.basedir}</contextDir>
                                        <tags>
                                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                                        </tags>
                                    </build>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

Until today - the docker folder was directly under the project root, so having the dockerFile element with the value ${project.basedir}/docker/Dockerfile was working fine ... but when I moved the docker folder under src/main - then builds started failing.
Info

docker-maven-plugin version : 4.4.0
Maven version (mvn -v) : 3.9.6
Docker version : 27.2.0


Do you need a Dockerfile? The jib maven plugin can package JVM apps without one

Yes, I have custom stuff I need to put in the docker image, which will be used further down the road.

Jib can still add files - https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-maven-plugin/README.md#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image
